# Trying to run a Symfony project on my computer

Tags: php, apache, webserver, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to run a Symfony project that I cloned from a GitHub. I've never used Symfony before but I'd like to run the project.

I read you needed to run `frontend_dev.php` so I ran that in to my browser:

`C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\Project\WebInterface\web\frontend_dev.php`

But just got a blank page with some PHP on it. I believe I may have to set up a web server but I'm not sure and figured I'd ask here first.

If I wanted to run the project from my computer, would I just download an Apache server and drop it in the root directory? What variables and files would I need to change to get it working properly? Do I need to forward any ports?

Comment: OMG, you need to have Web-Server running and configured for that.

Comment: @RomanNewaza: Yeah I figured as much. Does everyone still use Apache for this kind of stuff?

Comment: There are much better alternatives today than Apache. Use Google!

Comment: @RomanNewaza: Just linked me a huge tutorial and told me to use Google for a specific question. Can this project be used with apache or equivalent web servers (if you have a preference please say so), and if so, what needs to be changed due to the project running on a different system?

Answer (score 1):

Symfony 1.x branch is not supported anymore. Use Symfony 2.

Anyway, concerning your question: here is the doc for 1.4: [Day 1: Starting up the Project](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/01?orm=Propel)

Comment: The project was written in Symfony 1.4.

Comment: Buddy, everything is covered there. Fight your laziness and read the doc!